# Correct method to get and set data using CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I'm having an issue with CoreData, I set some data in the AppDelegate. Then later in a view controller's class I get those values and display them in a list view. When I try to fetch the values the in the view from CoreData I get nothing back.

This is the code I'm using to create the context:

```
public func createMainContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {

    let modelUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ItemModel", withExtension: "momd")
    guard let model = NSManagedObjectModel.init(contentsOf: modelUrl!) else { fatalError("model not found") }
    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
    try! psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
    return context
}
```

This is the code I'm using to get the values:

```
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Topic")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = createMainContext()

    let result = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)


    debugPrint("---- \(result)")
```

Insert a new Entity

```
let context = self.createMainContext()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Topic", into: context)  

entity.setValue(name.stringValue, forKey: "name")
```

When I set the values initially I perform a fetch & I can see the values, however, when perform a fetch from another view I get nothing back.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what I'm doing wrong or a correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Show how you create the entries in CoreData.

Comment: Added in main question above, I set the name of the topic to a stringValue

Comment: Each time you call createMainContext() you create a new context, each with its own, and separate in-memory store.  You add the new objects to one context/store, but your view controller is using a different (empty) context/store.